# sap crystal report and if statment for different value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using `if else` `crystal report` statment for testing different values and make result value for returning it but there is always some error. This is the code that I made:

```
stringvar resultvalue := "";
NumberVar countervalue := 2;

if {Table1.ENTEDABBADAL} = 0
then
(
    resultvalue := resultvalue + "" 
)
else 
(
    countervalue := countervalue + 1 ;
    resultvalue := resultvalue + "(" & i & ")يصرف له بدل انتداب لمدة يومين بناءً على المادة 22/18 من نظام الخدمة المدنية" + ChrW(13)
)

if {Table1.TARH7EELBADAL} = 0
then
(
    resultvalue := resultvalue + "" 
)
else
(
    countervalue := countervalue + 1;  
    resultvalue := resultvalue + "(" & i & ") يصرف له بدل ترحيل راتب شهرين بناءً على المادة 27/5 من نظام الخدمة المدنية" + ChrW(13) 
)

if ({Table1.TABLEEKH} = 0)
then
(
    resultvalue := resultvalue + ""
)
else 
(
    countervalue := countervalue + 1 ;
    resultvalue := resultvalue + "(" & i & ")يبلغ هذا القرار مع الاساس لإدارة شؤون الموظفين ومن يلزمه لاعتماده";
)

return resultvalue;
```

But it gives me an error. How can I solve this problem?
Inside the `if condition` different value testing and inside `if` make result value for displaying it in crystal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula in Crystal Reports must return a value.
Crystal Reports assumes `return` is the name of the variable.
Remove `return` in `return resultvalue;`.

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks Markus Sfar . this is the right code. but there is another problem. i i install crystal report runtime in client memory and press print order in crystal report not give me printers option > give me this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" how can i solve this problem

Comment: This happens when Crystal Reports is not updated or printer drivers is not updated.

Try another default printer.
Enable the option "No Printer" and "Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Paper Size".

Answer (score 0):

stringvar resultvalue:="";
NumberVar i:=2;

if {Table1.ENTEDABBADAL}=0
then

resultvalue:=resultvalue + ""

else
(
i:=i+1;
resultvalue:=resultvalue+"("&totext(i,0)&")يصرف له بدل انتداب لمدة يومين بناءً على المادة 22/18 من نظام الخدمة المدنية"+ChrW(13) 
);

if {Table1.TARH7EELBADAL}=0
then
 resultvalue:=resultvalue + ""
else 
(
i:=i+1;
resultvalue:=resultvalue+"("&totext(i,0)&") يصرف له بدل ترحيل راتب شهرين بناءً على المادة 27/5 من نظام الخدمة المدنية"+ChrW(13) 
);

if({Table1.TABLEEKH}=0)
then

resultvalue:=resultvalue+ ""

else
(
i:=i+1;
resultvalue:=resultvalue+"("&totext(i,0)&")يبلغ هذا القرار مع الاساس لإدارة شؤون الموظفين ومن يلزمه لاعتماده" 
)